# Asynchronous Request not returning anything on the first click

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I'm having a strange problem. I build an asynchronous search with Coldfusion and JQuery. Basically, when you search something and submit the search form it should fire off `Coldfusion.Ajax.submitForm` which calls some page with the results. I started to notice that the first time you do a search, it doesn't retreive anything. After that it works just fine.

Any ideas of why this is happening?

Note: I've checked firebug and the requests and good.

I'm not exactly sure as to why this is happening so I'm not sure what code I should post...here is my JQuery:

http://pastebin.com/i4HUBqFQ

Here is the form:

```
<div class = "span-22" id = "page-content">
<h3>Syllabi Management</h3>
<div class = "span-22" id = "searcharea">
<h4>Search</h4>
<form name = "search_syllabi" id = "search_syllabi" action = "">
<table width="450" border="0" align="center">
<tr>
  <td>
    <input name="searchstr" type="text" id="searchstr" size="45" />
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Search" style = "width: 80px;"/>
    <select name="department">
      <option value = "">Select a Department</option>
      <cfoutput>
        <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(session.departments)#" index = "i">
          <option value = "#session.departments[i].code#">#session.departments[i].name#</option>
        </cfloop>
      </cfoutput>
    </select>
    <select name="semester" id="semester">
      <option value = "201108">Fall 2011</option>
    </select></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</form>

</div>
<cfdiv class="span-22" id="SearchResult" bind="url:results.cfm?Search={searchstr}&semester={semester}" />
<div class = "span-22" id = "search_results">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first... verify if the problem is on the client end of things or the CF end of things.

When you say you've "checked firebug and the requests [are] good", what do you mean?  So like the request is being made, *and* the correct data is being returned?  Because that's what I'd take as being "good", however your post's heading says the request is not returning anything, which doesn't sound like it's "good" to me.  What *is* it returning (it must be retuning *something*).

Comment: Bah, sorry. I'm kind of bad at explaining problems. Forgive me. It 'acts' like the request went through ok, but something goes wrong that is not detected. It seems to be generating the data on the GET request for the cfdiv. It seems to be calling GET before my form POSTS. I'm starting to think it has something to do with interference with the JQuery...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the JQuery was not firing to unhide the data on the first click.

To fix it, I used `.load` instead of the `cfdiv`.